# What does the notation $(F_p^{\times})^2$ mean where $F=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: group-theory

What does the notation $(F_p^\times)^2$ mean, where $F=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$?

I was taking this (in two previous questions) to mean the cross product of $F=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, but I am beginning to realize that this might be what I am confusing here.

Thanks.

Comment: You write superscript $x$. Perhaps it was a superscript $\times$ instead?

Comment: first take the multiplicative group of units.  then square them all.  e.g. $p=5, (\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})^{\times}=\{1,2,3,4\}, ((\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})^{\times})^2=\{1,4\}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is a ring, then $A^*$ or $A^\times$ denotes the set of [units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_%28ring_theory%29) of $A$. Under the multiplication of the ring, this is a group, e.g. $\mathbf Z^* = \{\pm 1\}$. In a field $k$ all non-zero elements have inverses, so $k^* = k - \{0\}$.

Then $k^{*n}$ is the image of the map $k^* \to k^*$ given by $x \mapsto x^n$. It's somewhat confusing, since you could also imagine this standing for an $n$-fold direct product of copies of the group $k^*$, or for the set of all $x_1 \cdots x_n$ with $x_i \in k^*$.